# Puppeteer is calling in a loop in nextjs

Tags: node.js, api, next.js, youtube, puppeteer

I have a nextjs page which consists of a react video player which plays a YouTube video based on some id passed in the url. The YouTube video is fetched in getServerSideProps based on the id. Then on the client side I am using /api/some-route to take a screenshot of that video player div using Puppeteer. Problem is when in api side I am opening a browser with Puppeteer with that particular URL, getServerSideProps is called and again my api/some-routes is getting called. So It has made a loop and is not finishing. How do I stop this?

My page:

```
export default function Home() {
useEffect(() => {
   if (typeof window === undefined) {
     return;
   }
   const url = window.location.href;
   setTimeout(() => {
     fetch(`/api/scrapper?url=${url}`)
       .then((res) => {
         res.json();
       })
       .then((data) => {
         console.log(data);
       });
   }, 10000);
 }, [params.slug[0]);
return (
   <>
     <Layout>
       <Frame id="capture" />
     </Layout>
   </>
 );
}


export const getServerSideProps = async ({ params }) => {
return {
     props: { params, serverData },
   }; 
}
```

/api/scrapper.js

```
 import puppeteer from "puppeteer";

export default async function My(req, res) {
  const url = req.query.url;
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);
  const img = await page.screenshot({ path: "output.png" });
  console.log("img", img);
  await page.close();
  await browser.close();
  return res.json("done");
}
```

Comment: You are passing the current url to your API, and in you /api/scrapper.js file, you are opening the same page using puppeteer, which is in turn calling `getServerSideProps` each time. `getServerSideProps` gets called each time the page is requested. Maybe you intended to pass a different url than `window.location.href` ?

Comment: You could add a query param when going to the page with puppeteer, e.g. `await page.goto(url?mode=capture);`. Then on the page add an earlier return inside the `useEffect` if the query param with the given value exists, e.g. `useEffect(() => { if (router.query.mode === 'capture') { return; } ... })`.